# Parsing JSON with an array in it in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have the below JSON object

```
{"tags":[{"id":4,"name":"ExampleTitle","Memes":["http://someURL.com","http://anotherurl.com"]}]}
```

I am trying to parse it into an object

```
struct TagModel {
   let id : Int
   let name : String
   let memes : [String]

   static func create( id: Int, name: String, memes: [String] ) -> TagModel {
       return TagModel( id: id, name: name, memes: memes);
   }
}
```

Below is the code I am running it through to parse it. But for some reason it fails on the Array of urls "Memes". It doesn't let me pass in an array into the currying method. Essentially I know the curry method that gets called on the line that starts let mkTag has the incorrect syntax. I haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax.

```
import Foundation

func parseTag(cat: AnyObject) -> TagModel? {
    let mkTag = curry {id, name, memes in TagModel(id: id, name: name, memes: memes) }

    return asDict(cat) >>>= {
        mkTag <*> int($0,"id")
            <*> string($0,"name")
            <*> array($0, "Memes")
    }
}

func parseMemes(cat: AnyObject) -> MemeModel? {
    let mkMeme = curry {URL in MemeModel(URL: URL) }

    return asDict(cat) >>>= {
        mkMeme <*> string($0,"URL")
    }
}

func parseJSON(parsedJSON: [String:AnyObject]) -> [TagModel] {
    let tags = array(parsedJSON, "tags") >>>= {
            join($0.map(parseTag))
    }
    return tags!;
}

extension TagModel : Printable {
    var description : String {
        return "Tag { id = \(id), name = \(name)"
    }
}

func toURL(urlString: String) -> NSURL {
    return NSURL(string: urlString)
}


func asDict(x: AnyObject) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    return x as? [String:AnyObject]
}


func join<A>(elements: [A?]) -> [A]? {
    var result : [A] = []
    for element in elements {
        if let x = element {
            result += [x]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    return result
}



infix operator  <*> { associativity left precedence 150 }
func <*><A, B>(l: (A -> B)?, r: A?) -> B? {
    if let l1 = l {
        if let r1 = r {
            return l1(r1)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func flatten<A>(x: A??) -> A? {
    if let y = x { return y }
    return nil
}

func array(input: [String:AnyObject], key: String) ->  [AnyObject]? {
    let maybeAny : AnyObject? = input[key]
    return maybeAny >>>= { $0 as? [AnyObject] }
}

func dictionary(input: [String:AnyObject], key: String) ->  [String:AnyObject]? {
    return input[key] >>>= { $0 as? [String:AnyObject] }
}

func string(input: [String:AnyObject], key: String) -> String? {
    return input[key] >>>= { $0 as? String }
}

func number(input: [NSObject:AnyObject], key: String) -> NSNumber? {
    return input[key] >>>= { $0 as? NSNumber }
}

func int(input: [NSObject:AnyObject], key: String) -> Int? {
    return number(input,key).map { $0.integerValue }
}

func bool(input: [NSObject:AnyObject], key: String) -> Bool? {
    return number(input,key).map { $0.boolValue }
}


func curry<A,R>(f: (A) -> R) -> A -> R {
    return { a in f(a) }
}

func curry<A,B,R>(f: (A,B) -> R) -> A -> B -> R {
    return { a in { b in f(a,b) } }
}

func curry<A,B,C,R>(f: (A,B,C) -> R) -> A -> B -> C -> R {
    return { a in { b in {c in f(a,b,c) } } }
}

func curry<A,B,C,D,R>(f: (A,B,C,D) -> R) -> A -> B -> C -> D -> R {
    return { a in { b in { c in { d in f(a,b,c,d) } } } }
}

infix operator  >>>= {}

func >>>= <A,B> (optional : A?, f : A -> B?) -> B? {
    return flatten(optional.map(f))
}
```

Updated: 
MemeModel

```
struct MemeModel {
   let URL: String

   static func create( URL: String ) -> MemeModel {
       return MemeModel ( URL: URL );
   }
}
```

Comment: I added the MemeModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let str: NSString = "{\"tags\":[{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"ExampleTitle\",\"Memes\":[\"http://someURL.com\",\"http://anotherurl.com\"]}]}"

struct TagModel {
    let id : Int
    let name : String
    let memes : [String]

    init(dict: NSDictionary) {
        id = dict["id"] as Int
        name = dict["name"] as String
        memes = dict["Memes"] as [String]
    }
}


var tagModels: [TagModel] = []
var error: NSError?
if let data = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary {
    for tag in data["tags"] as [NSDictionary] {
        let tagModel = TagModel(dict: tag)
        tagModels.append(tagModel)
    }
}
```

Okay, I have left nothing to the imagination now.

Comment: It would be nice to explain what your code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't this give me an NSDictionary and not the TagModel array?

Comment: Yes, but it's a simple matter of creating a `TagModel.init(dict: NSDictionary)` method that simply assigns the values from the keys to the properties. I'll edit the answer to show this.

Comment: Ah sorry I see what you were showing earlier now. Thank you.